# How to use AJAX in combo of PHP and MySQL to update value in table?

Tags: ajax

I created a php/mysql page, where exists table filled with rows composed from MySQL table. Now I would need to use Select - change selected option - to update a value in a table row, having ID of a number, but values of select options are not related to table row ids.

The select options in each row contains results of

```
SELECT DISTINCT(response_desc) FROM transactions;
```

returning me following options I would like to use in my PHP page as the select options:

```
PAID
UNPAID
CANCELED
```

My demand is to make the php page loaded with all the records within, and use the SELECT OPTION in some row to change the value in the table in certain column

## The structure of the MySQL table is like this:

```
id, int, Primary key
order_id, Int
order_payer, Varchar 255
order_email, Varchar 255
order_date, Date
order_amount, Decimal length 9, Decimals 2
response_code, Varchar 255
url, Varchar 255
response_desc, Varchar 50
```

==================================================

Now I know, this cannot be done without JS, but I have nearly no skills with JS. I am aware there needs to be something like onchange instead of ahref, and some part of JS script, together with another external php, I would use to update the database as per my requirements.

I simply want to make my page listing the content of the previously defined database table functional without any page submitting or resubmiting. Would there be, please, someone, who would be willing to provide me part of a code, I would be able to combine together, to make it functional?

Thanks in advance for any hints for me.

created the js sscript and also tried to create the new file, but these are only SELECT like methods. I need to have in onchange method also the Primary Key id, to make sure, that the UPDATED value is the right one I wanted.

Seems to me so far too complex. The results I've found here are from 2013 and does not bring anything related to AJAX update :(

Answer (score 0):

ANSWERED:

So it was just an easy trick to resolve after all.

Into the main page was added this part of JS

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#statedesc").change(function(){
            var mysqlid=$("#mysqlid").val();
            var statedesc=$("#statedesc").val();
            $.ajax({
                url:'update.php',
                method:'POST',
                data:{
                    mysqlid:mysqlid,
                    statedesc:statedesc
                },
                success:function(response){
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I also created a new file update.php, where the update SQL query was added.

The content of update.php is like this:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once("config.php");
$mysqlid = $_POST["mysqlid"];
$desc = $_POST["statedesc"];


$sql = "UPDATE `transactions` set `response_desc`='".$desc."' WHERE `id`=".$mysqlid;
if($con->query($sql)===TRUE){
    echo "DATA updated";
}
?>
```

where $mysqlid is just a primary key int in the table I wanted to update. Lines 2-4 can be removed, as I used them just for debugging.

So I hope it might help other people too.